# How to reshape table in iTEXT

Tags: java, itext, tabular

I'm using iTEXT with java to create a simple PDF which contains a table in a specific form.
I shape of my table in the PDF file should be something like this

[image]

EDIT:
I tried to use row span as in code

```
         cell1.setRowspan(2);
         cell1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
         cell1.setPaddingTop(-13);
         cell1.setPaddingBottom(10);
         PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2"));
         cell2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
         cell2.setPaddingTop(-13);
         cell2.setPaddingBottom(10);
         PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2"));
         cell3.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
         cell3.setPaddingTop(-13);
         cell3.setPaddingBottom(10);
         //cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
         Paragraph p= new Paragraph("توفة توفايات",arabic);
         Paragraph p2= new Paragraph("سناء علاء حسين",arabic);
         Paragraph p3= new Paragraph("سناء سءء~ حسين",arabic);
         p.setAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
         p2.setAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
         cell1.addElement(p);
         cell2.addElement(p2);
         table.addCell(cell1);
         table.addCell(cell2);
         table.completeRow();
```

In fact, I do not know if 'm doing row span in a right way because my PDF showed only `p` and `p2`, `p3` is no where in the PDF.

How can I do it ?

Comment: You ought to share what you have tried already. StackOverflow is about helping eachother solve problems. Rather than outsourcing development.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with `iText7`

```
File outputFile = new File("output.pdf");

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputFile));
Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

// table magic
Table table = new Table(new float[]{20f, 20f});
table.addCell(new Cell(1,2).add(new Paragraph("Lorem")));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Ipsum")));
table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Dolor")));
layoutDocument.add(table);

// close
pdfDocument.close();
```